Objects rendered black in Cycles
I've imported an FBX file containing CAD data from Navisworks (my typical workflow), but this time, it contains a sub-assembly that is rendering black in Cycles.
I've tried applying materials from other parts in the model, checked for overlapping geometry, checked UVs (not entirely sure what to look for here) but nothing seems to work.
Below is a file containing some of the problem geometry, along with some basic geometry.

Thanks in advance.

It's a problem of split normals, you need to go into the Data panel > Geometry Data > click on Clear Custom Split Normals Data:


That seems to have done it! How do I do this for bulk geometry - e.g. hundreds of parts?

I don't know, pressing Alt while pressing the button doesn't seem to work, maybe a script?

I found this script which seems to do the trick:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147475/clear-custom-split-normals-data-many-objects?rq=1
